# How to make environmental variables equal to ID Values in html

Tags: javascript, html, api, github

Below is my API reference call. I am using github so I put the key in a seperate file and protected that file using .gitignore.

The issue is I have no Idea how to get that key from my javascript file into the HTML data-key using a variable.

```
<div 
    id="wg-api-football-fixtures"
    data-host="api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
    data-refresh="15"
    data-date="2022-05-06"
    data-key = "NEED MY API KEY HERE!"
    data-theme="false"
    data-show-errors="false"
    class="api_football_loader">    
</div>
```

I'm new to this so I could be doing something wrong, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your api key file:

```
// api_key.js
var apiKey = "123456789ABCDEFGH";
```

Your main javascript file:

```
// main.js
document.querySelector('div#wg-api-football-fixtures').setAttribute('data-key', apiKey);
```

In your html file ...

```
<div 
    id="wg-api-football-fixtures"
    data-host="api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
    data-refresh="15"
    data-date="2022-05-06"
    data-key = "NOT_LOADED_YET"
    data-theme="false"
    data-show-errors="false"
    class="api_football_loader">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="api_key.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Just make sure that you call the code in main.js after you included the api_key.js and after the html is loaded.

Comment: I made all the changes you gave but the HTML stays as "NOT_LOADED_YET" instead of taking in the variable. You can see my repository here https://github.com/Footballify/Footballify.github.io